# Htaccess redirecting non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have searched the web all over for a good generic .htaccess script for redirecting non-www to www, and currently i'm using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine, but if i go to a subdomain www. will be added. Does anyone has a good working redirect .htaccess script?

Comment: how about this? server fault had a similar question

http://serverfault.com/questions/190589/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-without-hardcoding-using-htaccess

Comment: @kernalpanic doesn't work for me, it doesn't redirect at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vince What if the requested url is something like:

> http://www.abc.example.com

IMHO, I think with your method it would never be redirected to:

> http://www.example.com

How about this?

```
# Rewrite domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.([a-z1-9\-]+)\.([a-z]+)$ [NC] [and]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z1-9\-]+)\.([a-z]+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, you guys may find these references useful:

https://www.drupal.org/node/93603

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html